# Custom CRS: How to get the leaflet scale control to display mm (millimeter) and um (micrometer)

Tags: leaflet

Is there anyway to get leaflet to display values smaller than a meter? For instance, mm (millimeter), or um (micrometer) on the scale control?

Or if there is a plugin that does this?

I have a custom map with a custom CRS that uses virtual microscopy images.

I use the following code to create a map with values less than a meter however the scale control is really wide and doesn't go below a meter:

```
L.CRS.Meters = L.extend(L.CRS, {
    projection: L.extend( L.Projection.LonLat, {
      bounds: L.bounds([0, 0], [2160, 4096])
    }),
    transformation: new L.Transformation(1, 0, -1, 0),
    scale: function (zoom) {
        return Math.pow(2, zoom);
    },
    infinite: false
});

var customCRS = L.extend(L.CRS.Simple, {
  projection: L.extend( L.Projection.LonLat, {
     bounds: L.bounds([0, 0], [2160, 4096])
  }),
  transformation: new L.Transformation(1, 0, 1, 0),
  scale: function (zoom) {
    return Math.pow(2, zoom +7);
  },
  infinite: false
});

var map = L.map('vm', { zoomSnap: 0.2, crs: customCRS}).setView([3, 3], 3);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The specific piece of code that handles the rounding of the scale bar measurement and the (metric) units is the [`_updateMetric` method](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/blob/master/src/control/Control.Scale.js#L87):

```
_updateMetric: function (maxMeters) {
    var meters = this._getRoundNum(maxMeters),
        label = meters < 1000 ? meters + ' m' : (meters / 1000) + ' km';

    this._updateScale(this._mScale, label, meters / maxMeters);
},
```

Note that the [implementation of `this._getRoundNum()`](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/blob/f3e62712513242187a78871a444aae9b3e012220/src/control/Control.Scale.js#L114) will return an integer number, i.e. `1` minimum.

You might want to replace the implementation of `_updateMetric()`, to round up a *factor* of that number, and apply unit suffixes accordingly, e.g.:

```
L.Control.Scale.include({
  _updateMetric: function(maxMeters) {
    var maxMilliMeters = maxMeters * 1000,
        milliMeters = this._getRoundNum(maxMilliMeters),
        label = milliMeters < 1000 ? milliMeters + " mm" : milliMeters / 1000 + " m";

    console.log(this._mScale, label, milliMeters / maxMilliMeters);

    this._updateScale(this._mScale, label, milliMeters / maxMilliMeters);
  }
});
```

See a [working example here](https://plnkr.co/edit/mS1gyryA9zcllaGXRdiG?p=preview).

Comment: Excellent! Thanks so much, you answered my question! This worked well!