# Leaflet.js | Distance Bar on flatmap without using the Earths curvature

Tags: javascript, leaflet

Wanting to add the Scale/Distance Bar onto my map. However, after adding this:`myScaleControl.addTo(map);`, I have noticed that the Distance bar is taking the curvature of the earth into consideration, which is not applicable for my map.

My initial idea would be to make it so that the only factor that will affect the scale will be zooming in and out, and thus the distance/scale won't change when scrolling around my flatmap. But am not sure how to accomplish this. Or if there is a smoother method of accomplishing this!

Thanks for any help :)

Comment: Welcome to SO! Are you using L.CRS.Simple?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Custom CRS: How to get the leaflet scale control to display mm (millimeter) and um (micrometer)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55874278/custom-crs-how-to-get-the-leaflet-scale-control-to-display-mm-millimeter-and)

Comment: @ghybs Thanks for the warm welcome! I was not originally, however looking into the documentation for it it's exactly what I needed! Now I just need to re-create my coordiates, as was using LatLng before!